# Duplicated classes after making copy of Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I made a copy of the project I am working on to test some stuff (some autolayout workout). But the new copy has compilation errors of "duplicate class definition". When I checked the duplication I found out that the duplicated classes are in the original project I copied. So it's not in the new project yet it's considering it a duplication error.

I made some search and found that I can change the app name, scheme, and main folder names, but in vain.

How to solve this problem? The original project is working fine but every time I make a copy of it, the new copy doesn't work because of that error.

Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out !, i am using `PCH file (prefix)` which has some imports in it, the thing is that the `path` for that pch file in the `build settings` in the new copy is referring to the directory of  the PCH file **in the original project**, once i fixed it and make it refer to the PCH file **in the new project**